# psql command line / terminal keyboard shortcuts

Tags: postgresql, command-line, terminal, psql, shortcut

I would like to use psql at the command line in terminal on my mac to connect with my postgres DB.  I can connect to my database with psql and am able to enter sql commands in my terminal.  However, none of the typical terminal shortcuts work anymore.  For example, I would like to be able to repeat a sql query by pressing the "up" botton, move the cursor to the start of the query by pressing control-A, tab-complete the table name, etc.

Is there a way to enable these shortcuts?

Comment: show your terminal with errors. all mentionned above work for me

Comment: hmm.. if after sshing in with psql, I press the up botton, the command line echoes "^[[A"  or if I press control-A, it echoes "^A"

Comment: aha! stright after ssh, run `bash` and then try `psql`?..

Comment: thanks for trying to help vao tsun.  I edited my question because maybe we are talking past each other.  I type in psql, then I can start writing sql commands, but at this point, when I'm in sql land, none of the keyboard shortcuts work anymore.

Comment: After ssh, before running psql, does the arrow keys, tab completion etc works as you expected? If they do,but no longer working once in psql, then that probably means either psql was not built with readline support, or it had trouble loading the readline library. If they don't then it's probably something wrong with the shell settings on the machine.

Comment: It looks like your `psql` was built without support for `readline` or `libedit`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had seem to be due to install postgresql with anaconda. I fixed it with:

```
conda uninstall postgresql
```

Install homebrew to get a postgres version that works with readline

```
brew install postgresql
```